# SQL make COUNT() return total rows in query

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have a query in MySQL as follows (table names are changed):

```
SELECT 

t1.name,
t2.type,
if(data1 = "6", sum(coalesce(data2, 0) * coalesce(data3, 1)) as more_data

FROM table_main tm
    JOIN table1 t1 ON tm.t1_id = t1.id 
    JOIN table2 t2 ON tm.t2_id = t2.id
    WHERE day = '2018-01-01'
    GROUP BY t1.name, t2.type
    ORDER BY more_data DESC
```

This query returns around 400 results, but for some reason every time I try to count() anything it keeps returning random data and not 1 record giving the total amount of records given by this query, now I've tried to get rid of most of the query and only leaving the 'if'-statement as a select also gives the required results, but then still it won't let me use that value in the count() method, is there any way I can count the records from this query without getting random data>

Comment: `sum(case when data1 = "6" then coalesce(data2, 0) * coalesce(data3, 1) else 0 end) `

Answer (score 0):

Your conditional aggregation is turned inside out... Use a `case` expression inside `sum()` instead.

```
SELECT 

t1.name,
t2.type,
sum(case when data1 = "6" then coalesce(data2, 0) * coalesce(data3, 1) else 0 end) as more_data

FROM table_main tm
    JOIN table1 t1 ON tm.t1_id = t1.id 
    JOIN table2 t2 ON tm.t2_id = t2.id
    WHERE day = '2018-01-01'
    GROUP BY t1.name, t2.type
    ORDER BY more_data DESC
```